# How to re-open a closed leaf in Fossil cvs?

Tags: fossil

In my timeline I have closed a leaf that I did not have to close. Now, if I try to commit against that repository, I get the message:

> Cannot Commit against a closed leaf

Is it possible to re-open that closed leaf? And how?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [same](http://www.mail-archive.com/fossil-users@lists.fossil-scm.org/msg14388.html) question just popped up on the [fossil-users](http://lists.fossil-scm.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/fossil-users) mailing list. I'll repeat Andy Bradford's answer here:

> There is  an option open the  leaf in the  web UI (fossil ui).  Find the
>   checkin in the  timeline, click on it and then  click edit. There should
>   be a checkbox that says:
>
> *Cancel special tag closed*
>
> If you check it and save the changes, the leaf will no longer be closed.